# Solving Poisson's equation with two Dirac delta potentials

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am trying to solve $\nabla^{2}\phi(x,y)=V_{0}(\delta(x-a,0)-\delta(x+a,0))$
with boundary conditions $\phi(x=0,y)=0, \phi(x=b,y)=0$. Here $a=1, b=5$.
How one can solve it numerically in Mathematica. And then plot $\phi(x,y)$ for $x=-10,x=10, y=-10,y=10$, $V_{0}=1$. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by $\delta(x-a)$ in a two-dimensional PDE? Does it make any sense?

Comment: @user64494, the source and sink are placed along x axis.

Comment: Do you mean the two-dimensional distributions $\delta(x-a,0)$ and $\delta(x+a,0)$?

Comment: @user64494, thanks I have fixed this.

Comment: "y" has no boundaries. Is that intended ? More precisely : does "y" extends to +/- Infinity or have you forgotten the boundaries ?

Comment: andre314 it extends to +/- infinity. Or you may take this as far greater than width of x.

Comment: $\delta(x-a,0)$ makes no sense. It should be $\delta(x-a,y)$.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably not easy to solve the Poisson equation numerically. However, it can be solved analytically using the method of mirror images. One starts with the fundamental solution of the Poisson equation in 2D that reads
$$v(\vec{r})=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\log|\vec r|$$
and adds mirror images to assure that boundary conditions are fulfilled. Here we need infinitely many of them

```
ϕ[x_,y_,x0_,y0_]:=-1/(2π)Log[((x-x0)^2+(y-y0)^2)]
f[x_,y_]:=Sum[(ϕ[x ,y,a-2i b,0]-ϕ[x,y,-a-2i b,0]),{i,-200,200}]
```

where I limit the sum by a finite number. Now I can answer the second part of the question about the plot.

```
Plot3D[f[x,y],{x,-20,30},{y,-10,10},
 ColorFunction->"SunsetColors",
 MeshFunctions->{#3&}, Mesh->{{0}}, MeshStyle->Directive[Black,Dashed],
 PlotPoints->30]
```

[image]

or a little bit fancy `DensityPlot`

[image]